# Angular SSR ERROR in src/server.ts(17,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering

After many hours trying to see this great idea working, it outputs this error when typing “ npm run build:ssr”

please Help!

```
"ERROR in src/server.ts(17,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'.         
src/server.ts(19,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'.                    
src/server.ts(34,14): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to i
nstall type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.                      
src/server.ts(36,26): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to i
nstall type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.                      
src/server.ts(48,55): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to i
nstall type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.                      
src/server.ts(52,30): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to i
nstall type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.                      

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                        
npm ERR! errno 1                                                                
npm ERR! project-name@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles: `ng build --prod &&
 ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false`                                
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                          
npm ERR!                                                                        
npm ERR! Failed at the project-name@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles script
.                                                                               
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.                                                              

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                            
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cristian\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-26T03_08_
11_820Z-debug.log                                                               
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                        
npm ERR! errno 1                                                                
npm ERR! project-name@0.0.0 build:ssr: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles 
&& npm run webpack:server`                                                      
npm ERR! Exit status 1"
```

Comment: can you please share your `server.ts` file.

Comment: Do you have a public repo, like on github?

Comment: I have solved that by using file-relative paths for the imports

Comment: Any updates on this stuff, how did you fix it?